# DocPad: How do I prevent clashing of render-plugins?

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, shortcode, docpad

I'm writing my first plugin for DocPad and I'm really enjoying the process because it's actually pretty intuitive.

My plugin uses [shortcode-parser](https://github.com/derdesign/shortcode-parser) to parse shortcodes in my markdown-documents.

## Here's my problem:

The [marked-plugin](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-marked) for DocPad converts `"` to `&quot;`, which is totally expected behaviour. However, this breaks my plugin because what was `[tagname attribute="some value"]` becomes `[tagname attribute=&quot;some value&quot;]`.

## Possible Solution:

There is already [a plugin](https://github.com/field/docpad-plugin-shortcodes) out there that handles shortcodes. It circumvents this problem by using a file-extension. The reason I wrote my own plugin was (aside from learning DocPad) that I don't want to have to add file extensions to hundreds of documents just to enable my plugin.

**Are there any clean alternative besides using file-extensions to prevent render-plugins from clashing?** If there was, for example, a configuration-attribute to specify the order in which render-plugins execute – I would consider that a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went with using extensions. The resulting plugin can be found here, if anybody's interested: https://github.com/maximilianschmitt/docpad-plugin-shortcodeparser

If anybody has a better idea to solve this kind of issue, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be handy to have a plugin, that could provide predefined pipelines.
For example:

```
docpadConfig = {
    plugins:
        PLUGIN:
            main: '.html.md.eco'
}
```

With this plugin document with extension `.main` could be processed as if it had extensions '.html.md.eco'.

Not sure, but maybe it's possible to replace pipeline by some query like this:

```
docpadConfig = {
    collections:
        _main: ->
            @getCollection('html').findAllLive({extension:'main', }).on 'add', (model) ->
                model.setMeta({extensions:['html', 'md', 'eco']})
}
```